# Return exception with original request object

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to return a custom exception along with the requested object? We are creating .NET object representations of a Vendor's API and the closest match to doing what they do would be to throw an exception along with the requested data/object.

There are many ways to do this without exceptions, but I'm curious to see if anyone has done this before.

Comment: By along you mean *"the exception message should contain the request object"*?

Comment: We need way more details. What technology are you using? MVC? WebAPI? WCF? Are there only certain types of exceptions, or all exceptions need to return the request object? What is the end result you want - if you figure out what the result should look like, we can help you get there with whatever framework you're using.

Comment: Have you tried simply creating a custom exception class with "request" property?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Not necessarily, but that wouldn't be a problem. Basically a response that could trigger an exception, and would allow us to retrieve the requested object. Having the object within the exception makes sense, but I did not want to be that specfic. Thanks.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver I don't know what type of exception we are going to inherit from. Probably the base Exception. That decision make depend on how we handle getting the data. If it's difficult to pass data along with the exception, we may just add a custom error object within the request.

Answer (score 1):

Well just create a custom exception object as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx

And add one property holding your requested object or the parameters or whatever and throw your custom exception...